# While excuting the next instruction of writing satp, it showed in gdb: Cannot access memory at address

Tags: qemu, virtual-memory, riscv

I'm trying to implement virtual memory of a kernel under RISC-V (RV64 Sv39) with QEMU and OpenSBI, but fail to enable MMU.

```
    map_pages(&base_pgdir, 0, KERNBASE, KERNBASE, 0x0000000002000000, PTE_R | PTE_W | PTE_X);
    u_long satp = SATP_MODE_SV39 | (base_pgdir >> 12);
    asm volatile("csrw satp, %0" : : "r"(satp));
```

where `KERNBASE` is `0x80000000L` and `SATP_MODE_SV39` is `0x8000000000000000`. But while excuting the **next instruction** of **writing satp**, it showed in gdb:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x802024ec
```

Apparently, I have failed to create a page table. But when I tested with my `get_pa(pgdir, va)` and `debug_page(pgdir)` function, it showed:

```
pa=00000000802024ec
--------------------page---------------------
|0000000080000000->0000000080000000  RWX    |
|0000000080001000->0000000080001000  RWX    |
|0000000080002000->0000000080002000  RWX    |
|0000000080003000->0000000080003000  RWX    |
|0000000080004000->0000000080004000  RWX    |
|0000000080005000->0000000080005000  RWX    |
......
|0000000081e7f000->0000000081e7f000  RWX    |
---------------------------------------------
```

`0x802024ec` seems to have been identically mapped at `0x802024ec`.

I have no idea to figure out the reason or debug.

Is there **any possible reason** which causes the problem or **any way to debug** for the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

And I'll show my codes below:

Macro:

```
#define PTE_PPN0 0x000000000007fc00L
#define PTE_PPN1 0x000000000ff80000L
#define PTE_PPN2 0x003ffffff0000000L
#define PTE_PPN  0x003ffffffffffc00L

#define PPN0_SHIFT 10
#define PPN1_SHIFT 19
#define PPN2_SHIFT 28

#define PPN0(va) ((((u_long)(va)) >> PPN0_SHIFT) & 0x01FF)
#define PPN1(va) ((((u_long)(va)) >> PPN1_SHIFT) & 0x01FF)
#define PPN2(va) ((((u_long)(va)) >> PPN2_SHIFT) & 0x01FF)

#define PTE_OFFSET 0x0000000000000fffL
#define PTE_VPN0 0x00000000001ff000L
#define PTE_VPN1 0x000000003fe00000L
#define PTE_VPN2 0x0000007fc0000000L
#define PTE_VPN  0x0000007ffffff000L

#define VPN0_SHIFT 12
#define VPN1_SHIFT 21
#define VPN2_SHIFT 30

#define VPN0(va) ((((u_long)(va)) >> VPN0_SHIFT) & 0x01FF)
#define VPN1(va) ((((u_long)(va)) >> VPN1_SHIFT) & 0x01FF)
#define VPN2(va) ((((u_long)(va)) >> VPN2_SHIFT) & 0x01FF)

#define PTE2PA(x) ((x & PTE_PPN) << 2)
#define PTE2PERM(x) (x & 0x3ffL)
#define PA2PTE(x) ((x >> 2) & PTE_PPN)
```

Mapping function `map_pages` and `map_page`:

```
static void map_pages(u_long *pgdir, u_int asid, u_long pa, u_long va, u_int size, u_int perm) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += BY2PG) {
        map_page(pgdir, asid, va + i, pa + i, perm);
    }
}

int map_page(u_long *pgdir, u_int asid, u_long va, u_long pa, u_int perm) {
    if (pa < KERNBASE || pa >= KERNBASE + MEMORY_SIZE) { // magic
        return -E_INVAL;
    }
    u_long vpn0 = VPN0(va);
    u_long vpn1 = VPN1(va);
    u_long vpn2 = VPN2(va);

    u_long *pte2;
    u_long *pte1;
    u_long *pte0;

    if (*pgdir) {
        pte2 = &((u_long *)*pgdir)[vpn2];

        if (*pte2 & PTE_V) {
            pte1 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte2))[vpn1];

            if (*pte1 & PTE_V) {
                pte0 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte1))[vpn0];

                if (*pte0 & PTE_V) {
                    u_long original_pa = PTE2PA(*pte0);
                    if (original_pa == PTE2PA(PA2PTE(pa))) {
                        // add perm
                        tlb_invalidate(asid, va);
                        *pte0 = PA2PTE(pa) | perm | PTE_V;
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        // clear
                        if (--pa2page(original_pa)->pp_ref == 0) {
                            page_free(pa2page(original_pa));
                        }
                        goto map;
                    }
                } else {
                    goto map;
                }
            } else {
                goto create_pte0;
            }
        } else {
            goto create_pte1;
        }
    } else {
        goto create_pte2;
    }

    struct Page *pp;

create_pte2:
    try(page_alloc(&pp));
    *pgdir = page2pa(pp);
    pp->pp_ref++;

    pte2 = &((u_long *)*pgdir)[vpn2];

create_pte1:
    try(page_alloc(&pp));
    *pte2 = PA2PTE(page2pa(pp)) | PTE_R | PTE_W | PTE_V;
    pp->pp_ref++;

    pte1 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte2))[vpn1];

create_pte0:
    try(page_alloc(&pp));
    *pte1 = PA2PTE(page2pa(pp)) | PTE_R | PTE_W | PTE_V;
    pp->pp_ref++;
    
    pte0 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte1))[vpn0];

map:
    tlb_invalidate(asid, va);
    *pte0 = PA2PTE(pa) | perm | PTE_V;
    pa2page(pa)->pp_ref++;
}
```

Test function `get_pa` and `debug_page`:

```
u_long get_pa(u_long *pgdir, u_long va) {
    u_long vpn0 = VPN0(va);
    u_long vpn1 = VPN1(va);
    u_long vpn2 = VPN2(va);
    printk("%016lx\n", va);
    printk("%016lx\n", (va >> 12));
    printk("%016lx: %016lx: %016lx\n", vpn2, vpn1, vpn0);

    u_long *pte2 = &((u_long *)*pgdir)[vpn2];
    printk("pte2 = %016lx: %016lx\n", pte2, *pte2);

    if (*pte2 & PTE_V) {
        u_long *pte1 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte2))[vpn1];
        printk("pte1 = %016lx: %016lx\n", pte1, *pte1);

        if (*pte1 & PTE_V) {
            u_long *pte0 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte1))[vpn0];
            printk("pte0 = %016lx: %016lx\n", pte0, *pte0);

            if (*pte0 & PTE_V) {
                return PTE2PA(*pte0) | va & PTE_OFFSET;

            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

void debug_page(u_long *pgdir) {
    printk("--------------------page---------------------\n");
    for (u_long vpn2 = 0; vpn2 < BY2PG / sizeof(u_long); vpn2++) {
        u_long *pte2 = &((u_long *)*pgdir)[vpn2];

        if (*pte2 & PTE_V) {
            for (u_long vpn1 = 0; vpn1 < BY2PG / sizeof(u_long); vpn1++) {
                u_long *pte1 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte2))[vpn1];

                if (*pte1 & PTE_V) {
                    for (u_long vpn0 = 0; vpn0 < BY2PG / sizeof(u_long); vpn0++) {
                        u_long *pte0 = &((u_long *)PTE2PA(*pte1))[vpn0];

                        if (*pte0 & PTE_V) {
                            u_long va = vpn2 << VPN2_SHIFT | vpn1 << VPN1_SHIFT | vpn0 << VPN0_SHIFT;
                            _debug_page(va, *pte0);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printk("---------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the problem.

I solved the problem by removing the `PTE_R` and `PTE_W` from the page tables that I mistakenly added to the page tables.

My guess is that Sv39 sees a page table with an identifier other than `PTE_V` as invalid.